# camel-beanio deprecated and removed since 3.17. What's the replacement?

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm currently upgrading Camel from `3.2.0` to `3.18.0`.

On the `3.17.0` release, `camel-beanio` was removed (https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_17.html).

I didn't see why it was removed nor how to replace it on https://camel.apache.org/manual.

I know I can declare the dependency for `camel-beanio` in my `pom.xml` but I don't want to have a camel version of `3.18.0` and camel-beanio of `3.16.0`.

Any clue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

there isnt a replacement component . anyone arent maintaing the project github.com/beanio/beanioyou last commit about 7 month ago u can use for

```
xml > jaxb
csv -> apache commons csv
```

Answer (score 0):

An option can be [flatpack](https://flatpack.sourceforge.net/). It does not seem to support XML, but you can still marshal/unmarshal flat files. See [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/flatpack-component.html) for that.
Also camel [bindy](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/dataformats/bindy-dataformat.html) maybe an option.

If you necesairly need to use beanio, you can go for [beanio](https://github.com/beanio/beanio) 3, mentioned in post from Lee Gilbert and wrap it into custom data format to be used with camel.
Example can be:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.beanio</groupId>
            <artifactId>beanio</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.M3</version>
        </dependency>
```

```java
public class BeanIODataFormat<T> extends DefaultDataFormat {

    private final StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
    private final String streamName;
    private Class<T> destinationClass;
    private int skip;

    public BeanIODataFormat(String definition, int skip, Class<T> clazz, String streamName) {
        this.skip = skip;
        this.streamName = streamName;
        factory.load(definition);
        this.destinationClass = clazz;
    }

    public BeanIODataFormat(String definition, String streamName) {
        this(definition, 0, null, streamName);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Exchange exchange, Object graph, OutputStream stream) {
        Collection<T> collection = convertType(exchange, graph, Collection.class);
        Writer writer = convertType(exchange, stream, Writer.class);
        try (BeanWriter out = factory.createWriter(this.streamName, writer)) {
            collection.stream()
                    .map(entry -> convertType(exchange, entry, destinationClass))
                    .forEach(out::write);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(Exchange exchange, InputStream stream) {
        Reader reader = convertType(exchange, stream, Reader.class);
        BeanReader beanReader = factory.createReader(this.streamName, reader);
        beanReader.skip(skip);
        Iterator<Article> result = Stream.generate(() -> (Article) beanReader.read())
                .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
                .iterator();
        return result;
    }

    private static <T> T convertType(Exchange exchange, Object obj, Class<T> dest) {
        try {
            return exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().mandatoryConvertTo(dest, obj);
        } catch (NoTypeConversionAvailableException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void setDestinationClass(Class<T> destinationClass) {
        this.destinationClass = destinationClass;
    }

    public void setSkip(int skip) {
        this.skip = skip;
    }
}
```

and then usage in camel route

```java
        BeanIODataFormat<Article> dataFormat = new
                BeanIODataFormat<>("path_to.beanio.xml", "articles");
        dataFormat.setSkip(1);
        dataFormat.setDestinationClass(Article.class);

       from(...)
...
       .unmarshal(dataFormat, false)
...
       .marshal(dataFormat)
```

Answer (score -1):

Beanio v3 fork at https://github.com/beanio/beanio
Spring framework support removed in v3, no comments there on the camel-beanio support.