# Camel BeanIO Replacement

Tags: apache-camel, deprecated, spring-camel, bean-io

I know that after 3.16 version of camel BeanIO becomes deprecated and removed from camel.
I cannot seem to find a replacement.

I have seen some people write their own code to replace it but I am trying to avoid having to do that.
Does anyone have a better idea of replacement?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74109708/camel-beanio-deprecated-and-removed-since-3-17-whats-the-replacement